# How to configure dnsmasq as an authoritative DNS server?

Tags: debian, dns, dnsmasq

I'd like to setup `dnsmasq` as an authoritative DNS server, but can't find any good guides for it. So could somebody please post a sample configuration of `dnsmasq` as an authoritative DNS server (with some basic options, such as A records)? I'd also like to know the path of the configuration, just so I set it up properly.
**EDIT:** Some clarification on my use case:
I intend to setup an authoritative DNS server so I can have automatic renewal of Let's Encrypt certificates using the DNS-01 challenge.
What I *do not* understand:
I've breifly read over http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html, but I don't understand which options are required for a basic configuration in authoritative only mode, nor how to configure the options.

Comment: Did you look at http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand much of it, so that's why I'm asking for a sample configuration.

Comment: Start by explaining what you do not understand then... go back to the basics, state your question with all details on your use case.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've updated my question. If it still needs improvement, please post another comment telling me what information I should include. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

```
# Do not read /etc/resolv.conf
no-resolv

# Do not read /etc/hosts
no-hosts

# e.g. 
# Define the zone
auth-zone=example.com
# Set SOA record
auth-soa=12345678,admin.example.com
# Set A record
address=/www.example.com/10.2.3.4
# Set MX record
mx-host=example.com,www.example.com,10
# Set TXT record
txt-record=_acme-challenge.www.example.com,f0o...bar
```

I found a good example. https://www.onderka.com/computer-und-netzwerk/autoritativer-dns-server-mit-dnsmasq/

By the way, do you know acme-dns? 
https://github.com/joohoi/acme-dns

It's more suitable for automatic renewals of Let's Encrypt certificates.